# First obj in the list is not updating in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am iterating over a list of the object and saving them
I created a Method for update

```
def UpdateLeadgers(obj, leadger):
l = leadger.objects.filter(id__gte=obj.id).order_by('id')
print('update ', obj.total_amount)
diff = obj.total_amount - l.first().total_amount
print('--diff--' + str(diff))
for i in l:
    print(i.total_amount)
    print("-------")
    print(i.net_Balancse)
    i.net_Balancse += diff
    print("++++++++")
    i.save(updateProcessing=True)
    print(i.net_Balancse)
    print("_+_+_+_+_")
```

I am Actually updating Netbalancse
I call the UpdateFunction in save() method

```
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    c = CashInHandPerson.objects.all().first()
    if self.id == None:
        if self.transaction_type == 'Credit':
            c.current_Balance += self.total_amount
            self.net_Balancse = c.current_Balance
        else:
            c.current_Balance -= self.total_amount
            self.net_Balancse = c.current_Balance
        c.save()
    else:
        up = kwargs.pop('updateProcessing', {})
        if not up:
            UpdateLeadgers(self, CashLeadger)
    self.cashInHandPerson = c
    super(CashLeadger, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

its update all value but not the first one:

Suppose I have a list Like
[image]

Now if I update 200 to --> 300
Then it's not updating the **NetBalance** of 200 **Total Field**

Its update the below fields:

Result
[image]

Comment: Because in the end the save method of the object _itself_ gets called and the object although changed in the database is not refreshed with those values and still has the old `net_Balancse`.

Comment: Although I would say this is a very bad way, why even store this running total in the database? You yourself can see that just to save _one_ object you now need to save _multiple_ other objects. If you actually didn't save that value you could have simply gotten it using a [Window function (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions).

Comment: But the bellow objects save correctly. But where it start the only that obj not saving it self